# Kotlin Android studio_stop other apps when starting focus session

Tags: android

I'm making a focus app with kotlin Android studio using jetpack composable. which function that i need to stop users to use other app when the start a focus session. Is Window Manager works?
The focus session is 25 minutes, users can use other app when the focus session done.

figma example:

[image: figma example]